# Using Google Maps API to supply driving directions based on a given postcode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone suggest the simplest method using the latest Javascript Google API to display directions to a hard-coded postcode or address via a supplied address/postcode (e.g., from a text input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Google Directions API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/